# jQuery show div to all browsers opened together on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to call `<div class="notification">Test</div>` on onClick together on 2/3 browsers.

Example, I open 3 browsers:
Chrome
Firefox
Safari

Then when I click button `<button id="showNotification">Show<button>` on Chrome browser then that 3 browsers will show the `<div class="notification">Test</div>` together.

jQuery

```
$('.showNotification').on('click', function()
{
    $('.notification').show();
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="showNotification">Show<button>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: If you want something like that I would suggest your look into SignalR or socket.io

Comment: Yes, as @CarstenLøvboAndersen says you need to use web sockets.

Comment: Probably possible with ajax too

Comment: @toffler How is this possible with ajax?

Comment: @SilverSurfer, possible with ajax polling.

Comment: Any example of that?

Comment: Jup, as @Alexandru-IonutMihai said, ajax polling is an option

Comment: @HiDayurieDave .. I haven't tried what you want#t to accopmlish... but for my understanding, it should work if you have a DB running in the background... when you click your button, send an ajax call to set the DB status to something like `open`.

Your browsers should do the ajax polling, like every second to check if the status is `open` ... if so, show the notification

This is how you can do the polling with ajax
[Polling example](https://gist.github.com/hofmannsven/9964415)

Comment: @toffler if you have the example, that would be better :)

Comment: What is the use case here? Like just from users perspective, I'm wondering what the situation is where you'd need something like this? Because one thing that comes to mind is [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/), which is meant for developement/testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each browser or each browsers tab are independent of each other.

If you want to achive such kind of functionality, You can go for

**Ajax polling - continously check if notification arrives from server**

OR

**Socket Programming - Server to client communication**

**NOTE**: *Both require server.If you want to achieve without server then you can either go for localStorage or file storage.Means, whenever you click on show just store that into localstorage/file and continuosly poll for that value using ajax to show in other tabs.*

Answer (score 1):

All browsers have **independent** and its set session for that

its not visible what you can done in one browser directly to another browser

Comment: I'm just saying that if you want to answer, and not just to post a light comment, you should take care of what you write down. For example, take care of the punctuation, check if your sentences are English-compliant and have sense, check if your code is well-written... You spend one more _minute_ of your time, but the hundreds of users that read you may potentially save a total of _hours_. Maybe you'll find useful to read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Good work :)